# Using database id column as user session ID in Laravel project

Tags: laravel

I am just starting with Laravel. In my project, I need to declare the id column of the user table as the session ID. This is so that I can insert this ID in another table along with other data to identify the user that submitted information in the table. How can I do this, please?

I have searched on Google and here on Stack Overflow, but I am unable to get any help.

I expect to assign a session id to each logged in user. And to insert this ID with other data in another table when the user submits information.

Comment: It's highly discouraged to make session ID as the user ID from the user column. If a user is logged in, obviously he or she is submitting the form. Why do you need to use Session anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get id of logged-in user by `Auth::user()->id` or `auth()->user()->id` and you can use this every where you need.

One other simple way write relations and then work with relations.

Comment: Or `Auth::id();` or `auth()->id();`. Former one is preferred though (`Auth::id()`).

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @mohammed Hosseini, i used Auth::user()->id. but there was an error: class app\HTTP\Controller\Auth cannot be found. i solved this by adding Auth facade to my controller like this:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth
```

Also user id is protected. i accessed it by adding a public function to my Model like this:

```
public function getId(){ return $this->id;}
```